# Multiple languages in one HTML page

Tags: php, html

How do I use Danish and Polish in the same HTML output in php?

I just found out that the 2 languages are in 2 different character sets. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 9):

Just use `UTF-8` encoding. It will handle both (and others) sets.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Use UTF-8. The best option when applicable. The only one that ensures that if you have a form with text input field, any character entered by the user is transmitted correctly.
2. Use any encoding and represent characters not present in it using character references or entity references. For example, use ISO Latin 2 (ISO-8859-2), which covers Polish and is well supported by browsers, and represent the Danish additional characters using e.g. `&aelig;` for the letter æ.
3. Use ISO Latin 7 (ISO-8859-13, “Baltic Rim”). It covers both Polish and Danish. Support is good in modern browsers but may not be present in old versions.