# Best practice for having multiple natural (human) languages on one web page?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

Encoding using UTF-8. ( [Multiple languages in one HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019844/multiple-languages-in-one-html-page) ).

What are the best practices to display multiple human languages on a single web page correctly across different browsers (including Safari on iPad)?

What to use for the META language tag?

Working in Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't declare a language for the entire page if it doesn't make sense. Instead, use a HTML `lang` attribute for each `div` or `span` or what have you.

It's rare for sites to use detailed language annotations (and rarer still for them to be consistent and accurate) but I believe this would constitute best current practice.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need anything special. Indicating the language in markup is not needed for rendering. It is mostly a matter of principle only, but if you wish to use it, simply use `<html lang="...">` to indicate the dominant language and the `lang` attribute specifying another language for any block containing text in another languge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mixing right-to-left languages (arabic, hebrew) with left-to-right languages you need to declare the direction of text blocks. If most of the text is left-to-right you only need to declare the right-to-left paragraphs:

```
<html dir="ltr">
    <p>English text</p>
    <p dir="rtl">العربية text</p> <!-- should render as "text العربية" -->
</html>
```

Declaring the language is not as important, as tripleee and Jukka say.